# How to open a file in the /tmp folder in inkscape?

Tags: tmp, solus, inkscape

Some software I use uses inkscape to convert images from one format to another, as an intermediate step. This means that they write images to the `/tmp` folder, and attempt to use inkscape on those images to obtain the image format they need. However, on my system, inkscape doesn't like the `/tmp` folder.

When trying to open/edit an svg file in the `/tmp` directory using inkscape, e.g., `inkscape /tmp/test.svg` it throws the error/warning

```
** (inkscape:6528): WARNING **: Can't open file: test.svg (doesn't exist)
```

The file exists, and I can open it with Budgie's default viewer.

When doing something similar in the home folder, e.g., `inkscape ~/test.svg` the test file opens just fine.
Inkscape itself runs when calling `inkscape` somewhere in the `/tmp` folder, it just can't use files from the folder.

I am running Solus 4, and installed inkscape using `sudo snap install inkscape`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Snaps are [confined](https://docs.snapcraft.io/snap-confinement) and have limited access to your host system; they don’t have access to `/tmp`. You’re only supposed to open files in your home directory with Inkscape installed as a snap.

You could try re-installing the snap in classic mode, but I wouldn’t recommend that generally:

```
sudo snap install --classic inkscape
```

That flag is ignored anyway for strictly-confined snaps, which is the case with your Inkscape snap (as you discovered).

I recommend not trying to get around confinement for two reasons. The first is that it exposes your system more than necessary (which you could consider not a problem if you trust the snap). The second is that snaps are designed with confinement in mind, so even if you trust the snap, it might behave unexpectedly if it’s unconfined.

Comment: Trying that gives me the following warning: `Warning: flag --classic ignored for strictly confined snap inkscape`, which confirms your remark about snaps being confined. Out of curiosity: why would you not recommend installing snaps in classic mode?

Comment: Can you move the file, then open it?